# Gpath for JSON with nested findAll

Tags: json, groovy, gpath

I have the following response payload

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "catname": "Cat01",
    "items": [{
        "Name": "Item01",
        "id": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "Item02",
        "id": 3
    }]
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "catname": "Cat02",
    "items": [{
        "Name": "Item03",
        "id": 5
    }, {
        "Name": "Item04",
        "id": 6
    }]
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "catname": "Cat03",
    "items": [{
        "Name": "Item05",
        "id": 8
    }]
}
```

]

I want to retrieve a list of all the items.ids (but not the ids of their parents), So this: [2, 3, 5, 6, 8].
I've tried this `findAll{it}.items.findAll{it}.id` but it doesn't work. Any help would be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `findAll` here to iterate, and you can make use of `collectMany` to automatically flatten the list

Assuming your parsed json is in a variable `json`, you can simply do:

```
json.items.collectMany { it.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the answer :).
I needed to use flatten here

```
items.flatten().id
```

did the trick.
I got the answer from here: [How to search in anonymous and nested array using find or findAll in groovy's closures using REST-Assured library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476960/how-to-search-in-anonymous-and-nested-array-using-find-or-findall-in-groovys-cl)